# Nested if else in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a questionnaire question where participants had to order 10 items in the way they do their morning routine. From that I am trying to a typology. As in, if a respondant picked item 8 **then** item 9 **then** item 1 etc. they are catagorised a certain way.

I thought of using ifelse (see below) in order to capture the order of their answers but I am unsure it is the right way to go but also I'm struggling with the nested ifelse.

```
test <- test %>%
  mutate(Ens_decouv = ifelse(Q75_1_ == "A8",
                                  ifelse(Q75_2_ == "A9",
                                         ifelse(Q75_3_ == "A1",
                                                ifelse(Q75_4_ == "A2",
                                                       ifelse(Q75_5_ == "A7",1,0))))))
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe try `dplyr::case_when`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `case_when` here from the `dplyr` package:

```
test <- test %>%
    mutate(Ens_decouv = case_when(Q75_1_ == "A8" &
                                  Q75_2_ == "A9" &
                                  Q75_3_ == "A1" &
                                  Q75_4_ == "A2" &
                                  Q75_5_ == "A7" ~ 1,
                                  TRUE ~ 0))
```

Comment: Yes, lol Ive actually thought about it just as I posted it.

Comment: Thinking about code is the first step towards writing code, so I guess you're on the right track.